# Casting pointer to object to void * in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I've been reading StackOverflow too much and started doubting all the code I've ever written, I keep thinking "Is that undefined behavour?" even in code that has been working for ages.

So my question - Is it safe and well defined behavour to cast a pointer to an object (In this case abstract interface classes) to a void* and then later on cast them back to the original class and call method using them?

I'm fully aware that the code that does this is probably awful. I wouldn't even consider writing it like this now (this is old code which I don't really want to change), so I'm not looking for a discussion of better ways to do this. I already know how to write it better if I ever did this again. But if it's actually broken to rely on this in C++ then I'll have to look at changing the code, if it's merely awful code then changing it won't be a priority.

I would have had no doubts about something this simple a year or two ago but as my understanding of C++ increases I actually find I have more and more worries about code being safe under the standards even if it works perfectly well. Perhaps reading too much stack overflow is a bad thing for productivity sometimes :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are safe.

From C++(0x) draft,

§5.2.9/13 (for `static_cast`):

> A value of type pointer to object converted to “pointer to *cv* `void`” and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall have its original value.

§5.2.10/7 (for `reinterpret_cast`):

> Converting an rvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value.

(Of course, casting to an unrelated class is undefined behavior.)

Comment: While this behaviour is of course unchanged in C++0x, I don't think it good practice to quote from an unaccepted draft  standard to answer questions on the current state of the language.

Comment: Thank you. I feel rather stupid asking such a basic question after 10 years of C++ programming, but the more I learn about c++ the more I doubt myself sometimes. Does anyone else feel that way? ... Hmm, just me then.

Answer (score 8):

> So my question - Is it safe and well defined behavour to cast a pointer to an object (In this case abstract interface classes) to a void* and then later on cast them back to the original class and call method using them?

Yes – as long as you cast back to the *exact same* type. Otherwise, base class pointer adjustments may destroy the value of the pointer.

In practice, this is (probably) only relevant when using multiple inheritance: pointers to a derived class may differ in their physical address from pointers to their base class.

Answer (score 1):

We use this technique commonly to avoid having switch statements in every single class based on the environment you are using (web-based, Windows, Linux etc)

Use `void **` for references.

```
void ** detailObject;
```

Create a function to return the referenced object:

```
TheObject *TheClass::GetObject(){
    TheObject *object   =   (TheObject*)object;
    return object;
}
```

Just use the function as the object from now on.  e.g.  `GetObject()->Go()`;